# Адаптивность .htm страницы под различные форматы мониторов

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, адаптивность

Можно ли как-то подстроить сайт, сделанный под разрешение **1600х900**, к монитору под **1366х768**? Нужно подстроить сайт не только под ширину, но и под высоту так, чтобы не было скроллов. В плане того, я скрыть то их могу, но не хочется терять кусок сайта.
Думал, что оно автоматически подстроится, однако, не тут то было. Несколько объектов сместилось и увеличилось в размере. Вообще-м, полных крах. Пытался указывать width в %, говорили, мол, что это поможет. Но всё тщетно.
Может там какой-нибудь **js/jquery** есть, или можно как-то проверить адаптивность ***.htm*** файла, не имея возможности загрузки его на web-сервер?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@media screen and (max-width:1366px) and (max-height:768px) {
  /* тут заново описываем все классы */
}
```

В общем, медиазапросами подгоняй верстку. Открываешь хром дев тулз, там есть кнопочка, которая изменит режим отображения. Как её нажмёшь, сверху можно задать нужное разрешение и ориентацию. И вот в этом режиме подгоняй классы, коротые косячат. Как я не знаю. Марджины убирай, паддинги, шрифты меньше делай. Ну, там уже сам разберешься.[image: devtools]

И никаких JS/jQwery. Про второе вообще забудь! Простым цсс. Если не в курсах про медиазапросы, так почитай чуток. Там понимать ничего не надо. Синтаксис только.

Comment: Ого, спасибо огромное!

Comment: @НикитаБорискевич да не за что. Если ответ на вопрос был получен, отметь его галочкой. И вопрос закроешь, и мне + в карму :)